# Como retornar o valor do elemento usando Xpath?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade onde preciso retornar os títulos das notícias do site [G1 - Mundo](http://globo.com/mundo). 
Estou utilizando o HtmlAgilityPack.

Como exemplo, a primeira notícia do site aparece neste trecho de código após visualizar inspecionando o elemento pelo navegador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da notícia está localizando dentro de vários 'div's e retorna "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection" no meu código no vs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou um pouco perdido, como posso realizar este retorno dos títulos das notícias?

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser útil para alguém também.
Consegui retornar os títulos das notícias da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ele só retorna 10 notícias.